# Tango With Django - Django 2.0

Tags: python, django

Im practicing Tango With Django but having this unexpected error, which i am unable to debug.

views.py

```
def index(request):
    category_list=Category.objects.order_by('-likes')
    context_dict = {'categories':category_list}
    return render(request,'index.html',context_dict)

def show_category(request, category_name_slug):
# Create a context dictionary which we can pass
# to the template rendering engine.
    context_dict = {}
    try:
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
        pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category)
        context_dict['pages'] = pages

        context_dict['category'] = category
    except Category.DoesNotExist:

        context_dict['category'] = None
        context_dict['pages'] = None

    return render(request, 'category.html', context_dict)
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('',views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('category/<slug:category_name_slug>/',views.show_category,name = 'category_view')
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 200, unique=True)
    likes= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'


    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name




class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    URL = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

First part of views.py is over,im able to show list views of categories, but when i click any one of them then it gives error in traceback given below

```
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
```

[I have added picture of that error, please be seeing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuJiG.jpg)

[image]

templates

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rango</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Rango says...</h1>
  <div>hey there partner!</div>
   <div>
    {% if categories %}
     <ul>
     {% for category in categories %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'category_view' category.slug %}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
     {% endfor %}
     </ul>
    {% else %}
     <strong>There are no categories present.</strong>
   {% endif %}
 </div>
<div>
<a href="/rango/about/">About Rango</a><br />
<img src="{% static "images/rango.jpg" %}" alt="Picture of Rango" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

category.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Rango</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>
 {% if category %}
 <h1>{{ category.name }}</h1>
 {% if pages %}
 <ul>
 {% for page in pages %}
 <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
 {% endfor %}
 </ul>
 {% else %}
 <strong>No pages currently in category.</strong>
 {% endif %}
 {% else %}
 The specified category does not exist!
 {% endif %}
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Well apparently there are *Three* categories with as `slug`, `True`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So, what should i do next! When i  try to hit the url manually like category/python or django then it shows shows nothing on the screen but it shows no error in console at that time.

Answer (score 3):

in your case [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) method return more than one `Category` here:

```
category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug) # error
```

[from docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) :

Django will complain if more than one item matches the `get()` query. In this case, it will raise `MultipleObjectsReturned`.

Check in your database why you have three `categories` with same `slug` and remove them or change  `slugs`

Comment: Well, thanks now it works but partially! I have 3 instances of categories,python ,django,other framewoks, now no matter which option i click it shows first value means python all the time.. and slug name in not appearing on url,it shows True, exactly which i have shown in picture.

Comment: sir i have added it.

Comment: Sir detail view is changing as per our slicing if im giving first, then only first value in rendering and when im giving [1] or [2] respective pages are showing up in all three categories

Comment: can you change to `categories = Category.objects.all()` and after this `print(categories)` and say what you get ?

Comment: I changed slug to pk, now its working but i cant access urls present in the pages section.. I think it would be better i delete everything and do it from scratch.. 

well its showing all of its instances

 <QuerySet [<Category: Python>, <Category: Django>, <Category: Other Frameworks>]>